# MPI: MPI_Comm_spawn(...), MPI_Init(...) segmentation fault

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, mpi, openmpi

I have two programs: `parent.cpp` and `child.cpp`. `parent.cpp` spawns the child processes (namely, the executable file of `child.cpp`). Given this context, the problem I have is the following. These are very simple skeleton codes but I still attach the complete program at the end of the page.

I first compile those codes.

```
>> mpicc -o parent parent.cpp
>> mpicc -o parent child.cpp
```

Then run using

```
>> mpirun -np 1 parent
>> Parent rank 0, communicator: [some number] running
>> Child spawned
>> Child spawned
>> Child spawned
>> Child spawned
>> Child spawned
[AND THEN SEGFAULT]
```

This gives me an error saying:

```
...
Signal: segmentation fault (11)
Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
...
```

The bizarre part is if I do

```
>> mpirun -np 2 parent
```

The parent program runs, spawns and terminates successfully.

If you refer to my code below, I have a number of `printf` statements. From this, I realize that the SegFault occurs at `child.cpp` `MPI_Init(...)`. I have consulted Google, ChatGPT, BARD, Github issues, but I cannot seem to fix this error.

I am using *Open MPI 4.0.1.*

I have had a number of Github posts that are seemingly similar to my issue, but none of them provided solutions. I attach a link to those Github issues.

[OpenMPI 4.0.5 MPI_COMM_SPAWN child fails to MPI_INIT #8189](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/8189)

[OpenMPI 3.0.0 MPI_COMM_SPAWN child fails to MPI_INIT #4555](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/4555)

Any help and comments would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
// parent.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
  int i, a, b, nprocs, nWorker, myrank, flag, ierr;
  MPI_Request req;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Comm parent, children, intercomm;
  char worker_program[100] = "child";

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

  nWorker = 5;

  MPI_Comm_spawn("child", MPI_ARGV_NULL, nWorker, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &intercomm, MPI_ERRCODES_IGNORE);

  if (intercomm == MPI_COMM_NULL) printf("children spawn failed\n");

  if (myrank == 0) {
    int a = 101;

    for (i = 0; i < nWorker; i++) {
      MPI_Send(&a, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, intercomm);
      printf("Message sent\n");
    }

    MPI_Comm_free(&intercomm);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

```
// child.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
  int i, a, b, nprocs, nWorker, myrank, flag, ierr;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Comm parent;

  cout << "Child spawned\n";
  
  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

  cout << "Child MPI_Init()\n";
  
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
  MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent);
  
  MPI_Recv(&a, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, parent, &status);
  
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This spawning business is heavily system dependent. Can you install mpich on your system? Just to rule out something: what happens if you remove the send/recv calls over the inter communicator?

Comment: My issue outlined above occurs on a server running Linux in which I do not have sudo previlege nor does it have internet connection as it is a highly secure server. I would have loved to try with different MPI library and even Open MPI v5 which claims to have solved the issue but I am restricted to version 4.0.1. I tried running the same code on my local machine with Open MPI 4.1.5 and it completely solved the issue – which is ironic becuase I have not changed any code. So your speculation is probably correct; it must be a system issue. Any guess how I should go on about from here? Thanks